# Are there any disadvantages to not using XML when developing an android app?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android app development. A tutorial I am following uses XML with Java. I am proficient in Java but have never worked with XML. I was thinking of using only Java for developing my first app but was wondering whether there were any disadvantages to not using XML?

Comment: Your app can keep resources in xml; the, or at least one, disadvantage is not having that managed for you. Another, IMHO, is the time factor. You can reuse xml in ways java code can't, or at least without additional dependencies. An example would be generic views.

Comment: Is there some magical way of creating an Android layout without XML? Is there much call for console apps for Android?

Comment: @MarsAtomic, I don't think it's magical; just time consuming. You just do it programmatically.

Comment: You need to use at least some XML to make an Android project because every app needs an AndroidManifest.xml. Why not just learn XML? It's a simple human-readable format.

Comment: @samgak Do you know any good textbooks on XML? I think it would be beneficial for me if I took the time to learn it now.

Comment: @magic_broom You don't really need a book. The fact that XML is human readable makes its use reasonably self-evident. Just follow along with a few tutorials and you should readily pick up the fundamentals.

Comment: reading the Wikipedia page will tell you enough to use XML for android programming: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML While doing Android programming you'll spend more time learning the specific Android tags, which won't be covered in a generic textbook on XML anyway

Answer (score 0):

Think of xml as a code for the design of your app. if you know web development, you will probably be profiecent at it. for the layout of your app, you are shown to panels. one shows the phone itself and you can manually put whatever you want into that layout, or use xml to write it out. sometimes, its more efficient to use the manual layout, which automatically writes the xml code within the xml file, or sometimes its easier to write in xml. so you should learn a little bit about it, but unless you want to code the entire design of you're app, it doesn't really matter as much as knowing java.